# Python: How to match special characters in regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a regular expression match with special characters in it, such as "/", ".", and "-". 
This is the string:

```
17440 root      20   0 3645m 452m  12m S  152 11.8 347:32.04 test/1/02.3_4-6
```

But the following code does not seem to match at the end with :

```
m=re.search(r"(?P<pid>\d+) +(?P<user>\w+) +(?P<pr>[\w-]+) +(?P<ni>[\w-]+) +(?P<virt>\w+) +(?P<res>\w+) +(?P<shr>\w+) +(?P<st>\w) +(?P<cpu>\d+) +(?P<mem>\d.+) +(?P<time>[0-9:.]+) +(?P<proc_name>[\w-/.]+)", line)
```

Do I need backslash before the special characters, such as "/" and "."? 
Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output? Change `(?P<mem>\d.+)` to `(?P<mem>[\d.]+)`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `(?P<mem>\d.+)` in your regex to `(?P<mem>[\d.]+)` so that it would capture a digit or a dot one or more times or otherwise `\d.+` would match a digit and the following characters greedily. Because there are some other patterns exists  next to this `+(?P<time>[0-9:.]+) +(?P<proc_name>[\w-/.]+)`, this `(?P<mem>\d.+)` would make the regex engine to backtrack in-order to find a match.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a period '.' is a special character.

Escape it with a back slash.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html